# how to find the largest even palindrome number made from the product of two 3 digit numbers

Tags: java, arrays

```
package palindrome even;
public class PalindromeThreeDigits {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value = 0;
        for(int i = 100;i <=999;i++) {
            for(int j = i;j <=999;j++) {
                int value1 = i * j;
                StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(""+value1);
                String sb2 = ""+value1;
                sb1.reverse();
                if(sb2.equals(sb1.toString()) && value<value1) {
                    value = value1;
                }
                //Implementing the if statement to find the value
                if ( value %==0){
                    System.out.println( " highest value is" +value)
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

I am getting the result for only the largest number but not for the highest even number of palindrome

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The code is supposed to make an **even** palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the even test to the if statement that saves the largest number.

```
public class PalindromeThreeDigits {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j <= 999; j++) {
                int value1 = i * j;
                StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("" + value1);
                String sb2 = "" + value1;
                sb1.reverse();
                if (sb2.equals(sb1.toString()) && value < value1
                        && value1 % 2 == 0) {
                    value = value1;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(value);
    }

}
```